# Increase height of just one ItemRender

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, itemrenderer

I am trying to develop a Call Log with Flex, and I have some troubles with the ItemRenders. In fact, here is what I've got :

[image: The original state]

And when you click on an Item, the size of the Item changes to display more details :

[image: The clicked state]

But as you can see, every item are affected by this resize. The Tile Layout is taking the highest render and apply its height to the others.

Here is my code, where I call the Render :

```
    <s:DataGroup id="TileListUsers"
                 left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" width="300"
                 itemRenderer="assets.render.CallLogRender"
                 dataProvider="{ListCall}"
                 horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" contentBackgroundAlpha="0.0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="15" requestedColumnCount="1" verticalGap="15" />
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
```

And in the Render, I'm using three BorderContainer, one for the first block, one for the second block, and one for the details displayed between them :

```
        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
            super.data = value;

            CallerIDLabel.text = "Appel du : " + data.CallerID;
            StartHourLabel.text = data.StartHour;
            StartDateLabel.text = data.StartDate;
            if(value == null){
                return;
            }
            if (!data.Answer){      
                ShadowColor.color=0xCC9900;
                CallerIDLabel.text = "Appel manqué : " + data.CallerID;
                SourceIcon.source=callFinished;
            }   
        }

        private function onClick():void{
            if (data.Answer){
                this.height=170;
                DetailLineContainer.visible=true;
                SecondBlocContainer.visible=true;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:BorderContainer id="DetailLineContainer" x="0" y="39" width="100%" height="101"
                   backgroundAlpha="0.0" borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderVisible="false"
                   borderWeight="1" cornerRadius="5" visible="false" >
    <s:Line id="LineDetail" x="25" y="0" height="100%">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#aeaeae" weight="3" caps="square"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Line>
    <s:Graphic x="21" y="25" width="8" height="8">    
        <s:Ellipse x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor id="CircleColor" color="#5b5b5b"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Graphic>
    <s:Graphic x="21" y="53" width="8" height="8">    
        <s:Ellipse x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor id="CircleColor2" color="#5b5b5b"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Graphic>
    <s:Label id="DurationLabel" x="35" y="25" width="250"
             color="#929292" fontFamily="proxima" fontSize="13"
             text="Durée de l'appel : 13 minutes 23 secondes" textAlign="left"
             verticalAlign="top"/>
    <s:Label id="QualityLabel" x="35" y="52" width="250"
             color="#929292" fontFamily="proxima" fontSize="13"
             text="Qualité de l'appel : moyenne" textAlign="left"
             verticalAlign="top"/>
</s:BorderContainer>

<s:BorderContainer id="FirstBlocContainer" width="100%" height="50" click="onClick()" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                   borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderVisible="false" borderWeight="1" cornerRadius="5">
    <s:BorderContainer width="50" height="50" borderVisible="false" backgroundAlpha="0.0">
        <s:Graphic id="Shadow" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" bottomLeftRadiusX="5" topLeftRadiusX="5">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor id="ShadowColor" color="#70b13c"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Graphic>
        <s:Image id="SourceIcon" horizontalCenter="0"
                 source="@Embed('/assets/images/CallLogIncomming.png')" verticalCenter="0"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:Graphic id="CallState" x="0" bottom="0" width="100%" height="2%" alpha="0.15">
        <s:Rect x="0" y="-1" width="260" height="2">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Graphic>
    <s:Label id="CallerIDLabel" left="60" width="180" color="#5B5B5B" fontFamily="proxima"
             fontSize="14" maxDisplayedLines="2" text="Appel du : 0636360400" textAlign="left"
             verticalAlign="middle" verticalCenter="0"/>
    <s:Label id="StartDateLabel" y="10" right="5" width="50" color="#C0C4C3" fontSize="12" text="08/04/14"
             textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:Label id="StartHourLabel" y="24" right="5" width="50" color="#C0C4C3" fontSize="12"
             text="12:45" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
</s:BorderContainer>

<s:BorderContainer id="SecondBlocContainer" x="0" y="117" width="100%" height="50"
                   backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderVisible="false"
                   borderWeight="1" cornerRadius="5" visible="false" >
    <s:BorderContainer width="50" height="50" borderVisible="false" backgroundAlpha="0.0">
        <s:Graphic id="CallState2" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" bottomLeftRadiusX="5" topLeftRadiusX="5">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor id="ShadowColor2" color="#B1463C"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Graphic>
        <s:Image id="SourceIcon2" horizontalCenter="0"
                 source="@Embed('/assets/images/CallLogFinished.png')" verticalCenter="0"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:Graphic id="Shadow2" x="0" bottom="0" width="100%" height="2%" alpha="0.15">
        <s:Rect x="0" y="-1" width="260" height="2">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Graphic>
    <s:Label id="CallerIDLabel2" left="60" width="180" color="#5B5B5B" fontFamily="proxima"
             fontSize="14" maxDisplayedLines="2" text="Vous avez raccroché" textAlign="left"
             verticalAlign="middle" verticalCenter="0"/>
    <s:Label id="StopDateLabel" y="10" right="5" width="50" color="#C0C4C3" fontSize="12" text="08/04/14"
             textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    <s:Label id="StopHourLabel" y="24" right="5" width="50" color="#C0C4C3" fontSize="12"
             text="12:45" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Is there a way to say to the TileLayout to just increase the height of one component without affecting the others ?

Comment: try adding attribute variableRowHeight="true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `TileLayout` if you have only one column? Use `VerticalLayout` and set its `variableRowHeight` property to true. Here's an [example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/19/creating-a-variable-row-height-spark-dropdownlist-control-in-flex-4/).

Comment: This is the current view, but the user can choose to display it on many columns and it will adapt on his screen's resolution.

Comment: You can always write your own layout

Comment: OK, it is working with a VerticalLayout ! Thank you !